# my app media play in background mode didn't play if once I open apple music app

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, avplayer

I have problem with media play in background mode.
In my app I have to play media play in background mode when server send any notification through socket connection.
In my case media player working fine when app in background mode.
Problem is when app in background mode if I play music app and stop the music player and send notification to my app .Than my app didn't play media player.
I added in plist this one "App plays audio or streams audio/video using AirPlay"
I am using "AVPlayer"

Please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the `AVPlayer` documentation it says that it can only play one asset at a time. I think Apple Music uses if not the same API something that is related to this.

> AVPlayer is intended for playing a single media asset at a time. The
>   player instance can be reused to play additional media assets using
>   its replaceCurrentItem(with:) method, but it manages the playback of
>   only a single media asset at a time

Answer (score 0):

**1). Put this code in you AppDelegate.m (didFinishLaunchingWithOptions) methods :**

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
```

**2). After that set Background Modes active for Audio, Airplay and Picture in Picture**

[image]

Comment: I have already added these code in AppDelegate and Background Modes also on.

Comment: From my side its working perfect. but i used YMCAudioPlayer for play music.

Comment: Please test you app by following step:
1.Open you app play media.
2.Stop player.
3.Open apple music app and play musics ,then stop music.
4.Now your app is on background mode.Now in background mode try to play your app media player.
Let me your result

Answer (score 0):

Might be, its due to Interruption with current AVplayer running item.

Also, take care you implemented it(Below code)before loading any item to AVPlayer. AND enabled Capabilities to Play audio in background.

```
NSError *myErr;
[self becomeFirstResponder];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];  

AVAudioSession *aSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

[aSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&myErr];

[aSession setMode:AVAudioSessionModeDefault error:&myErr];

[aSession setActive: YES error: &myErr];
```

Implement and Add Interruption handler, so you can re-play your stopped audio after another audio/interruption stopped. and below listener of it will call.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(handleAudioSessionInterruption:)
                                             name:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification
                                           object:aSession];
```

And manage AVplayer play/pause again in it:

```
- (void)handleAudioSessionInterruption:(NSNotification*)notification {

    NSNumber *interruptionType = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey];
    NSNumber *interruptionOption = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptionKey];


    switch (interruptionType.unsignedIntegerValue) {
        case AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeBegan:{
            // • Audio has stopped, already inactive
            // • Change state of UI, etc., to reflect non-playing state
            IsInteruptionOccured=YES;
        } break;
        case AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeEnded:{
            // • Make session active
            // • Update user interface
            // • AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptionShouldResume option
            IsInteruptionOccured=NO;
            [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
            if (interruptionOption.unsignedIntegerValue == AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptionShouldResume) {
                // Here you should continue playback.
                // Resume after exteranl interruption.


                     [_audioPlayer play];


                BOOL isPlayingWithOthers = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] isOtherAudioPlaying];
                // test it with...
                NSLog(@"other audio is playing %d",isPlayingWithOthers);
            }
        } break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```